# Is there a technique to use a W ^ X mechanic in HTML5 to fight XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I wonder if it is possible to tell the Browser to only Execute JS Code that is in the  tags in the initial loading of the page. Thus not executing any  tags that were inserted dynamically by JS Code with

```
element.innerHTML = "<script>XSSCode</script>"
```

I think this might make many XSS attacks impossible.

Edit:  `el.innerHTML` is only one example of adding a new script 
tag to a Webpage.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different proposals in your question.

> ...if it is possible to tell the browser to *only* execute JS code that
>   is in the tags in the initial loading of the page

You would then prevent code splitting and force everyone to bundle full scripts. Also, there is `document.head.appendChild(...)`, where child is `document.createElement("script")` - this functionality kind of creates a script for "initial loading of the page" right in the `<head/>`. It is a bad idea in many ways to prevent appending scripts to document's DOM.

> tags that were inserted dynamically

...it is a different proposal. If you are saying browser still allows JS to create `script` tags from within the code, but `el.innerHTML` should not allow `script` tag at all, this might not be too limiting for certain cases. You can achieve it e.g. by overriding `Element.prototype`'s innerHTML. It is still a bad idea, but might help prevent a certain attack.

An example of the code is in accepted answer here:
[Change innerHTML set on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560085/change-innerhtml-set-on-the-fly)

In essence, you would do:

```
  var originalSet = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML').set;
  Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML', {
    set: function (value) {
        // change it (ok)
        var new_value = value.toString().replace(/<script/g,"");

        //Call the original setter
        return originalSet.call(this, new_value);
    }
  });
```

It is not very robust and I would not use it in production. But I could imagine it might help to detect a problem with third party script.